# Solving the SIR model to calculate new cases within a defined time interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equations for S, to then assess S within a set time interval.

Within the SIR model S is the susceptible population in an epidemic and how it reduces over time as the population infected (I) grows then recovers.

I'm trying to solve for S to calculate within a set time interval (assume time interval is days and so solve for new infections in days 5-8):

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=-\lambda S$$

$$\frac{dI}{dt}=\lambda S - \gamma I$$

where: $$\lambda = \beta\frac{I}{N}$$ and: N is constant.

to solve: $$\int_5^8 \lambda Sdt$$

I'm struggling to solve the differential equations, any help would be greatly appreciated!